# Incorrect xtick setting python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got an csv file, which contains five days of data, everything is set in few columns. The problem was that every measurement was set every 5 minutes, so during one day I have 288 rows, which for 5 days is 1440 and it goes like this (0:00, 0:05, 0:10 ...).

I used this code to plot everything in one plot, but somehow aranging `xticks` doesn't work properly.

Here is the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels([v for v in data.Time], rotation=45)
ax.plot(x, data.Decfreq)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 1440, 60))
```

Plot I receive:

[image]

My data:

`00:00 7.680827152169027 0.14000897718551028 7.600809170600135 0.23361947896117427
00:05 7.650820409080692 0.1564676061198724 7.530793436727354 0.2561764164383169
00:10 7.630815913688469 0.15549587808153068 7.540795684423466 0.2576230038042995
00:15 7.820858619914587 0.17966340911411277 7.540795684423466 0.28225658521669184
00:20 7.540795684423466 0.17165693216100902 7.50078669363902 0.2630767707044145
00:25 7.670824904472915 0.13538117325249963 7.390761968981794 0.24547505458369223
00:30 7.84086311530681 0.18094062831351296 7.630815913688469 0.26532083891716435
00:35 7.9608900876601485 0.14987576886445067 7.660822656776803 0.25499025558872285
00:40 7.200719262755675 0.12533028213451503 7.120701281186783 0.23856516035634334`

Where only first (time) and second (data) columns interest me.

Implementing code by @Anwarvic I've got this:

[image]

Comment: why doesn't it work properly?

Comment: Because when setting `np.arange(1, 1440, 60)`, I thought I will get xaxis that will look like this `0:00, 5:00, 10:00, 15:00, 20:00, 1:00...`

Comment: Could you post the data used to draw this graph? Just a small sample enough for me to reproduce your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from your comment, the problem is within the label, not the ticks themselves. You need to skip `60` from the `data.Time` and change `set_xticklabels` just like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xticks(x)
values = data.Time.values
ax.set_xticklabels([values[i] for i in range(0, len(values), 60)], rotation=45)
ax.plot(data.Decfreq)
```

And there is no need for the `plt.xticks()` part as it's the same as the `ax.set_xticks()`.

### EDIT

I don't know how come your plot is far different than mine. Here is my code using [this sample data](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pg2xlaiv3kffucy/sample.csv/file) that I created to look exactly like yours:

```
data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
x = np.arange(0, 1440, 60)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xticks(x)
# ax.set_xticklabels([v for v in data.Time], rotation=45)
values = data.Time.values
ax.set_xticklabels([values[i] for i in range(0, len(values), 60)], rotation=45)

ax.plot(data.Decfreq)
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot:
[image]

So, my advice is to try changing my csv file with yours with few differences and see if it works

Comment: I've edited my question by adding result of your solution.